# const vs new const

Tags: c#

No matter what I Google, there doesn't seem to be an answer for this!  In a C# class, what does the new keyword do to a const field?

e.g:

```
private const int ConstOne = 0;
private new const int ConstTwo = 0;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `new` keyword is used when hiding a member from a base class.
It doesn't actually do anything; it just tells the compiler not to warn you that you're hiding the base field.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

The new keyword is used when hiding a member. It works for all class members like methods, fields, etc.

Basically hiding is used to declare that you know that you are going to hide a member and are aware that it is not going to be used in polymorphic scenarios unlike when you are overriding a member.

Google for hiding vs overriding. For example:
http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_polymorphism.html